# what benefits would i get by rewriting my page as an AMP?

Tags: amp-html

I recently published a web page for a local business. I designed the page to be mobile first and very fast. It scores 100 on PageSpeed Insights. It just needs one 20Kb request to get interactive, and it takes 1.1 seconds.

Profiling the page on my own mobile phone connected to the Internet by 4G, took 0.7 seconds to get interactive.

The page has all artifacts (css, html, javascript and svg icons) inlined except images. Images are loaded as you scroll.  It has 682 words and 8 svg icons.

Google gtag script is deferred 8 seconds after page load.

After publishing the page, I came accross to this AMP thing. And I wonder if I should rewrite the page as an AMP.

is it really that fast?. The first thing an AMP page does is loading the amp script, this script is 60kb gziped, 3 times compared to the one request I need to get interative.

So the question is. Would I really get performance benefits?

and. What other benefits would I get?

this is the page: https://acupuntura-madrid.es/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that it doesn't make sense for you to use AMP. Your page is already very fast and it's faster than the AMP version. Well done!

Theoretically, the AMP version could load faster when surfaced in Google Search due to [pre-rendering](https://developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/the-speed-benefit-of-amp-prerendering.html). However, your page will not always be pre-rendered and it's going to load fast in any case.

AMP has a few additional benefits though:

- static layout avoiding annoying content jumps
- [well-tested components](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/) that are easy to use
- ads and analytics require a lot less resources
- your page will stay fast as more features get added (due to the way it's designed)

If these matter in your case is something that you need to decide.

Comment: Thanks for your response. One more thing. Would the AMP version get a higher page rank?